# Inject Foreign key in new record in Entity Framework Core: create a new child record with foreign key of parent

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, entity-framework-core

I'm a total newbie to EF Core and I'm building a CRUD Application to manage my company's back end.

**Bundle.cs**:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace AdminPortal.Models
{
    public partial class Bundle
    {
        public int      Id          { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartUtc    { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndUtc      { get; set; }
        public int      Quantity    { get; set; }
        public int?     AgreementId { get; set; }
        public decimal? BundlePrice { get; set; }

        public virtual Agreement? Agreement { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Agreement.cs**:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace AdminPortal.Models
{
    public partial class Agreement
    {
        public Agreement()
        {
            AgreementAmendments = new HashSet<AgreementAmendment>();
            Bundles = new HashSet<Bundle>();
            Invoices = new HashSet<Invoice>();
        }
 
        public int     Id                { get; set; }
        public int     OrgId             { get; set; }
        public string? AgreementNumber   { get; set; }
        public string? IrespondReference { get; set; }
        public string? DocumentLink      { get; set; }

        public virtual Organization Org  { get; set; } = null!;
        
        public virtual ICollection<AgreementAmendment> AgreementAmendments { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Bundle>  Bundles  { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
    }
}
```

- An `Agreement` can have many `Bundles`.

  - ...but a `Bundle` can only have one `Agreement`.
- When I want to view the `Bundles` associated to an `Agreement` the Bundle view loads as it should with only the associated Bundles.
- When I click on the *Add New Bundle* button I want it to 'remember' what `Agreement.Id` it was derived from, so when I click on *Save* the Controller will be able to create a new record with the right foreign key.

This is what the POST controller action looks like:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create( [Bind("Id,StartUtc,EndUtc,Quantity,AgreementId,BundlePrice")] Bundle bundle )
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(bundle);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(bundle);
}
```

The GET Action method in the BundlesController.cs is:

```html
// GET: Bundles
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int? id)
{
   return _context.Bundles != null ?
   View(await _context.Bundles.Where(p => p.AgreementId == id).ToListAsync()) :
                        Problem("Entity set 'unidContext.Bundles'  is null.");
        }
```

and the View/Index.cshtml:

```html
@model IEnumerable<AdminPortal.Models.Bundle>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}


<div class="container">
    <div class=" row pt-4">
        <div class=" col-6">
            <h2 class="text-white">Bundle List</h2>
        </div>
        <div class=" col-6 text-end">
            <a asp-controller="Bundles" asp-action="Create" class=" btn btn-primary">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-plus"></i> &nbsp; Add Bundle
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br />

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr style="color:aliceblue; background-color:#126E75">
                <th>
                    Quantity
                </th>

                <th>
                    Start Date
                </th>
                <th>
                    End Date
                </th>
                <th>
                    Price
                </th>
                <th scope="col" colspan="3" style=" width:10%; text-align:center">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
            <tr class =" table-light">
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartUtc)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EndUtc)
                </td>

               <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AgreementId) 
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BundlePrice)
                </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center">
                        <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">
                            <i class="fas fa-edit" style="color:darkolivegreen"></i>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center">
                        <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-eye" style="color:blue"></i>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center">
                        <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">
                            <i class="fas fa-trash" style="color:red"></i>
                        </a>
                    </td>
            </tr>
    }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Bundle Create view:

```html
@model AdminPortal.Models.Bundle

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Bundle</h4>
<hr />

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StartUtc" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="StartUtc" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="StartUtc" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="EndUtc" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="EndUtc" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="EndUtc" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Quantity" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Quantity" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Quantity" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="AgreementId" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="AgreementId" class="form-control" value=@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.AgreementId) />
                <span asp-validation-for="AgreementId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="BundlePrice" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="BundlePrice" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="BundlePrice" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Could someone please point in the right direction.

Comment: Don't use EF entity classes _directly_ as root `@model` objects in ASP.NET MVC (and ASP.NET Core MVC) nor as DTOs in ASP.NET Web API because this will cause no end of problems (I can explain in detail if you're interested). Instead you should design a suiitable DTO and to/from mapping functions to map data from/to the "`BundleDto`" and the internal `Bundle` entity class.

Comment: This is how VS set them up.  I scaffolded my Db and then ran the add controller with views wizard and that's what it came up with :)  Unfortunately I barely know enough at this stage to ask a question never mind understand the answer so if you could kindly expand on what I should do I'd very much appreciate it.

Comment: Before I can continue, please post the defintiion of your `GET` action handler, I'd also like to see your View (`.cshtml`) where you render your form.

Comment: Ok, I will edit the post adding the GET handler and the view.

Comment: Where is your `<form>` ?

Comment: Sorry.  Now included in post.

Comment: You need `<form method=“post”>`

Comment: This is zero help to me. Where do I need form method = post and how will that create a bundle of which has the foreign key set to the required parent. Maybe read the question again???

Comment: Your `<form>` is being submitted as a GET request, not as a POST request, that's why.

Comment: No it isn’t. It is an [HttpPost] method called Create which is referred to by the asp-action =“Create” on the submit button in the create bundle form. And even if it was, your suggestion doesn’t even touch on the main question about the foreign key reference in the post method. Maybe read the question again?